# How to get height of Keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

The height of a keyboard on varying iOS devices is different. Does anybody know how I can get height of a device's keyboard programmatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284321/what-is-the-height-of-iphones-onscreen-keyboard

Answer (score 277, accepted):

## Swift

You can get the keyboard height by subscribing to the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification. (Assuming you want to know what the height will be before it's shown).

#### Swift 4

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
    name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
    object: nil
)
```

```swift
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
    }
}
```

#### Swift 3

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
    object: nil
)
```

```swift
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
    }
}
```

#### Swift 2

```swift
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

```swift
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardFrame: NSValue = userInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.CGRectValue()
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why the guy here http://www.think-in-g.net/ghawk/blog/2012/09/practicing-auto-layout-an-example-of-keyboard-sensitive-layout/ checks for isPortrait. Won't  keyboardRectangle.height be still correct in all orientations?

Comment: yes, in swift 3 its messed. giving different value every time

Comment: NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil) is the right syntax

Comment: What if you already have the keyboard visible, and you rotate the device, how do you find the new keyboard height?

Comment: Use this for **Swift 4**: `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` in the name bit

Comment: How can I access the keyboardHeight variable in viewDidLoad()? I tried reassigning it using something like KBHeight = Int(keyboardHeight).

Comment: It doesn't work with the keyboard without the toolbar! (for example, if selected Ukrainian language)

Comment: Why is the dict value being cast as an NSValue?  You should update this, it should be cast as CGRect like:  (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)?.height

Answer (score 64):

#### Swift 3.0 and Swift 4.1

1- Register the notification in the `viewWillAppear` method:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

2- Method to be called:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        print(keyboardHeight)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, you can also have the `keyboardWillShow` parameter be of type `Notification` to make this more Swift 3.0 compliant.

Comment: when we call the function keyBoardWillShow(), what exactly do we put as the argument? I have added the first line in viewDidLoad, and the function in the class... but I'm not sure how to call it haha

Comment: @VDog you don't call it, iOS will call it when the keyboard is shown

Comment: Registering for the notification in `viewDidLoad` is not a good idea: where do you put the matching `removeObserver` call so that when this VC is no longer being shown, it stops getting notifications? It is better to put the registration for notifications in `viewWillAppear`, and then put the `removeObserver` call in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: @xaphod you right, `viewWillAppear` seem to be a better place to register notifications, I will update my post. Removing the observer in no longer necessary unless you are supporting older versions (>= iOS8). Thanks. Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter

Comment: You need to change "UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey" to "UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey" because in your example you often can get zero height. 
The details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689664/ios-11-keyboard-height-is-returning-0-in-keyboard-notification

Comment: I tested the original key 'UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey' and it did not always provide the correct value. Then changed to 'UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey' per @andreylanadelrey's comment and it fixed the issue. Updated answer text to use the new key.

Answer (score 34):

**Swift 4 and Constraints**

To your tableview add a bottom constraint relative to the bottom safe area. In my case the constraint is called tableViewBottomLayoutConstraint.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewBottomLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillAppear(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillDisappear(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow , object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide , object: nil)
}

@objc 
func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification?) {

    guard let keyboardFrame = notification?.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
        return
    }

    let keyboardHeight: CGFloat
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    } else {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
    }

    tableViewBottomLayoutConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
}

@objc 
func keyboardWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification?) {
    tableViewBottomLayoutConstraint.constant = 0.0
}
```

Comment: The first answer to any of these questions that takes into account safe areas. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

**Update Swift 4.2**

```
private func setUpObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: .keyboardWillShow, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}
```

selector method:

```
@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardRectValue = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectValue.height
    }
}
```

extension:

```
private extension Selector {
    static let keyboardWillShow = #selector(YourViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)) 
}
```

**Update Swift 3.0**

```
private func setUpObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: .keyboardWillShow, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}
```

selector method:

```
@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardRectValue = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectValue.height
    }
}
```

extension:

```
private extension Selector {
    static let keyboardWillShow = #selector(YourViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)) 
}
```

**Tip**

UIKeyboardDidShowNotification or UIKeyboardWillShowNotification might called twice and got different result, this [article](http://blog.seancarpenter.net/2012/10/07/uikeyboarddidshownotification-called-twice/) explained why called twice.

**In Swift 2.2**

Swift 2.2 deprecates using strings for selectors and instead introduces new syntax: `#selector`.

Something like:

```
private func setUpObserver() {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: .keyboardWillShow, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}
```

selector method:

```
@objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {

    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.CGRectValue()
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
    editorBottomCT.constant = keyboardHeight
}
```

extension:

```
    private extension Selector {

    static let keyboardWillShow = #selector(YourViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)) 
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the observer in deinit, e.g.: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)

Answer (score 17):

## Swift 5

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //  Registering for keyboard notification.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}


/*  UIKeyboardWillShowNotification. */
    @objc internal func keyboardWillShow(_ notification : Notification?) -> Void {
        
        var _kbSize:CGSize!
        
        if let info = notification?.userInfo {

            let frameEndUserInfoKey = UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
            
            //  Getting UIKeyboardSize.
            if let kbFrame = info[frameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
                
                let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
                
                //Calculating actual keyboard displayed size, keyboard frame may be different when hardware keyboard is attached (Bug ID: #469) (Bug ID: #381)
                let intersectRect = kbFrame.intersection(screenSize)
                
                if intersectRect.isNull {
                    _kbSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.size.width, height: 0)
                } else {
                    _kbSize = intersectRect.size
                }
                print("Your Keyboard Size \(_kbSize)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is excellent answer. When software keyboard is hidden, this result is correct.

Answer (score 11):

Shorter version here:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        }
}
```

Comment: what argument do you pass for keyboardWillShow under notification?

Comment: Hard to tell, I was replying to the code block of the poster...but it corresponds with this line (let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!)

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4** .

Simplest Method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {  

      if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
             let keyboardHeight : Int = Int(keyboardSize.height)
             print("keyboardHeight",keyboardHeight) 
      }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C version:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

and then:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
CGFloat height = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

// Step 1 :- Register NotificationCenter

```
ViewDidLoad() {

   self.yourtextfield.becomefirstresponder()

   // Register your Notification, To know When Key Board Appears.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SelectVendorViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

   // Register your Notification, To know When Key Board Hides.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SelectVendorViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

// Step 2 :-
    These Methods will be called Automatically when Keyboard appears Or Hides

```
    func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
        let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        tblViewListData.frame.size.height = fltTblHeight-keyboardHeight
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification) {
        tblViewListData.frame.size.height = fltTblHeight
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method by ZAFAR007 updated for Swift 5 in Xcode 10

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

}




@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let keyboardHeight : Int = Int(keyboardSize.height)
        print("keyboardHeight",keyboardHeight)
    }

}
```

Comment: This gives differing heights after the first time it is called during a program execution.

Answer (score 1):

I uses below code,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.registerObservers()
}

func registerObservers(){

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillAppear(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@objc func keyboardWillAppear(notification: Notification){
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -keyboardHeight)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification){
        self.view.transform = .identity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I had to do this. this is a bit of hackery. not suggested.

but i found this very helpful*

**I made extension and struct**

**ViewController Extension + Struct**

```
import UIKit
struct viewGlobal{
    static var bottomConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
}

extension UIViewController{ //keyboardHandler
 func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
 }
 func listenerKeyboard(bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint) {
    viewGlobal.bottomConstraint = bottomConstraint
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    // Register your Notification, To know When Key Board Hides.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
 }
 //Dismiss Keyboard
 @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
 }
 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5){
        viewGlobal.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
    }
 }

 @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5){
        viewGlobal.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
    }
 }
}
```

**Usage:**
get most bottom constraint

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! // default 0
```

call the function inside **viewDidLoad()**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    listenerKeyboard(bottomConstraint: bottomConstraint)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Hope this help. 
-you keyboard will now **auto close when user tap outside of textfield** and 
-**it will push all view to above keyboard** when keyboard appear.
-you could also used **dismissKeyboard()** when ever you need it

Answer (score -1):

if let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
{
let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
print(keyboardHeight)
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).