# Can an ios app get the type of keyboard being used?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

In my app, I would like to know whether or not the user is using the default system keyboard. If they are using the default system keyboard, I would like to get the keyboard's frame so that I can use it to place a view directly above (eg. on the top of my app's window).

Is there anyway to get the current keyboard type and view, programmatically?

Comment: Why do you want to do something different if they’re using another keyboard?

Comment: Get the keyboard's frame (no matter what kind of keyboard it is) from the appropriate keyboard notification.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774006/how-to-get-height-of-keyboard-swift