# iOS 11 - Keyboard Height is returning 0 in keyboard notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have been using Keyboard notifications without any problem and getting exact height of Keyboard.

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *) notification{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    NSLog(@"%f",keyboardSize.height);}
```

but with iOS 11 the size of keyboard is 0 when the notification is called.

What is the problem occurring in this scenario? I am using xcode 9 Beta 5

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Use this:

```
CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

For Swift, you can use:

```
let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size
```

Comment: Changing from UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey to UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey did the trick, thx.

Comment: @Akshay Just startframe and endframe of the keyboard in respective screen bounds.

Answer (score 102):

Replace `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`

with

`UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

The below is from Apple Docs.

> UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey- The key for an  NSValue  object
>   containing a  CGRect  that identifies the start frame of the keyboard
>   in screen coordinates.
>
> UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey - The key for an  NSValue  object
>   containing a  CGRect  that identifies the end frame of the keyboard in
>   screen coordinates.

Comment: Apple needs to update their example code then, because it doesn't work anymore on iOS 11.  Also from Apple docs, where they use UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: Solved my problem!  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Can someone explain to me like I'm 5-years-old what the difference between these two is, and why this makes a difference when it comes to getting the UIScrollView to scroll automatically? I would really appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: It's not working after tap to a textfield with numPad. if after numPad I tap to the general textfield, keyboard not up anymore and when it dismiss view get down

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

Replace `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

Comment: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];`the method keyboardWillChangeFrame:is not only run once,maybe twice,or more.Maybe some keyboard have special toolbar on top sometimes,the method will run many times at this time.So,you should replace **UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey** with **UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey** to get the final frame of the keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is happening on iOS 11.

> Replace
>
> "UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey" with "UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"
>
> as shown below would fix the issue

Objective-C Code :

```
CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

Swift 2.3 :

```
let keyboardSize = (NfnPsgVar.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
```

Swift 3 :

```
let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue using Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235); although I was using Swift. In my keyboardWillShow method I wrote the following:

```
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

    let heightValue = keyboardSize.height    

    ...
}
```

Strangely, the first time keyboardWillShow was called, heightValue was 216.0, but during subsequent calls it had become 0! Perhaps this is an Xcode bug.

I replaced the UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey with a UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey, and it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I noticed the same thing. It also seems to only apply to the very first time the keyboard shows. Keyboards on additional view controllers reported the height as 0 the first time it showed for that view controller.

Answer (score 4):

Calculate keyboard height using the below code.

> **It is working for both devices with the safe area and non-safe area devices.**

## Code:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    guard let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
            return
        }    
    let keyboardHeight: CGFloat                    
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
       let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
       let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0.0
       keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height - bottomPadding
    } else {
       keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is trying to get the frame height before it is shown, and that is why it should be 0 which I am not sure why it is not at the first try! Here is an example of how to correctly get the keyboard height in swift 4.2:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {

    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }

    guard var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }

    keyboardFrame = view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

    let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.height
}
```

This will correctly provide the keyboard frame properties **BEFORE** keyboard appears.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough we get accurate keyboard height when we adjust BottomSpace Constraints from SafeArea it makes more empty space. So we have to subtract safeArea margin from keyboard height if we are going to adjust the bottomSpace Constraints.

```
    @objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
                  
    
                  if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
                      var bottomPadding: CGFloat = 0
                      //IF device is latest including iPhone x, it will have bottom padding as safeArea Insets. So we have to subtract that from REAL Keyboard HEIGHT.
                      if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first{
                        bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
                      }
    
                      let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
                      let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height - bottomPadding
                      bottomSpaceConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
                  }
                  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
              }
```