# My XIB popup is acting weird on iOS 10 and above

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I've been pulling my hair for hours now regarding my xib popup acting weird in iOS 10 and above, this problem happens when textFieldDidBeginEditing is fired, [here is video of the issue](https://youtu.be/GMG8R7rtm94). Code for xib popup:

**After a few times debugging this problem. I noticed that the textFieldDidBeginEditing not cause this weird issue. What I suspect is a MJPopupViewController which caused this issue.**

```
#import "NewPopView.h"
#import "UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.h"

@interface NewBottlePopView() <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
@end
@implementation NewBottlePopView
@synthesize viewController;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

-(void)showPopUpInViewController:(UIViewController *)controller{

    if ([controller class] == [UINavigationController class]) {
        viewController = [(UINavigationController*)controller visibleViewController];
        [viewController setKeepOnTouchOutside:NO];
        [viewController presentPopupView:self animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
    }else{
        viewController = controller;
        [viewController setKeepOnTouchOutside:NO];
        [viewController presentPopupView:self animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
    }
}

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
    [viewController dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
}


#pragma mark Text Field Delegate
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"screen width: %f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width);
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width <= 320)
    {
        //CGFloat newY = -textField.frame.origin.y - self.frame.size.height;
        CGFloat newY = -textField.frame.origin.y + 140;

        if (newY >= self.frame.origin.y)
            newY = self.frame.origin.y;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                                    newY,
                                    self.frame.size.width,
                                    self.frame.size.height);   //resize
        }];
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.tag == 202)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"[^\\d]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
        textField.text = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:textField.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [textField.text length]) withTemplate:@""];
    }

    textField.text = [textField.text uppercaseString];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
//    [self tapBackground:[self.gestureRecognizers firstObject]];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
{
    textField.text = [textField.text uppercaseString];
    NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
    // Try to find next responder
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
    if (nextResponder) {
        // Found next responder, so set it.
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self tapBackground:[self.gestureRecognizers firstObject]];
    }
    return NO; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    textField.text = [textField.text uppercaseString];
    return YES;
}

-(void)tapBackground:(UIGestureRecognizer*)getsure{
    [self endEditing:YES];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self setCenter:viewController.view.center];
    }];
}

@end
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem as I cannot thinking anymore. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you look for `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width` instead of the height? You should detect if the height is not enough to have the keyboard.frame.origin.y and yourview.frame.origin.y+yourview.frame.size.y, no ?

Comment: Wow. That is the first time I have ever seen anyone use YouTube to show off the problem. Good job +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for this problem by following this post :

> [iOS 11 - Keyboard Height is returning 0 in keyboard notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689664/ios-11-keyboard-height-is-returning-0-in-keyboard-notification)