# UiTextfield does not move up when Keyboard pops up ios 11 (Working on Previous versions)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

PROBLEM : not working in ios 11 (However working in ios 8)

The following code is written in Swift 2.0. But my application is too large to migrate the code at one go and to release an update.

Aim :
I want to give a release with xcode 7 but i get a 'developer disk image' when debugging on ios 11.
So how can i fix the bug without migrating the code

```
func viewDidLoad(){

    super.baseScrolllView = scrollView
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardAdjust:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardAdjust:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}
```

Code in Base class

```
var keyboardIsVisible = false
var baseScrolllView: UIScrollView!
func keyboardAdjust(notification: NSNotification) {

    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight:CGFloat = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().size.height
    let duration:Double = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double

    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    keyboardFrame = self.view.convertRect(keyboardFrame, fromView: nil)

    if notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification && keyboardIsVisible == false{

        keyboardIsVisible = true

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { ()

            var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.baseScrolllView.contentInset
            contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
            self.baseScrolllView.contentInset = contentInset



        })


    }else {
        keyboardIsVisible = false

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { ()
            var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            self.baseScrolllView.contentInset = contentInset
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689664/ios-11-keyboard-height-is-returning-0-in-keyboard-notification/45689725#45689725)

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava Thanks for the reply........Do you mean that i am not calculating the height of keyboard properly

Comment: Yes I think that u are not calculating it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I get the height of keyboard

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo, 
          let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue, 
          let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else { return }

    containerViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) { 
        self.containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```