# How to get height of emoji keyboard in iOS 11 when switching input type immediately?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I am using the code below:

```
CGRect keyboardFrame = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
```

but it doesn't work exactly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689664/ios-11-keyboard-height-is-returning-0-in-keyboard-notification

Comment: I'm using UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey but i want to continue getting the height when switching input type (means while keyboard is shown)

Answer (score 4):

You can subscribe to notifications: [UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1621623-uikeyboardwillchangeframe) or [UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1621619-uikeyboarddidchangeframe) . In handlers [you can get the end frame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/keyboard_notification_user_info_keys)  of the keyboard.
[Here](https://github.com/K-Be/KeyboardNotifications)  I’ve created an example application.

Comment: when switching keyboard type from ASCII to emoji, it does not send UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame/UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame notification.

Comment: If a keyboard frame really will change,  notification will send. You can exam it in a my example application: https://github.com/K-Be/KeyboardNotifications . (Rotate a device to landscape and switch to Emoji)

Comment: Thank you! but did you try to switch keyboard input type to emoji when keyboard is displayed?

Comment: Yes I did. You can download my example and see it.

Comment: I have test, UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification won't be called when input change to emoji

Comment: A reason to post the notification is a changing of a frame of a input view. If a phone in a portrait orientation with a hints panel, frame will not change.

Answer (score 2):

When switching to emoji keyboard by pressing the language selector button (the globe), it seems that a `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame`-notification gets sent. But when changing by long pressing the language selector button, no notification is sent.

It looks to me as a bug in iOS 11, since even the apple messages app and facebook messenger app doesn't handle this right. I've submitted a [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=36657137) about this with id: 36657137

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour on iOS 11, same issue here.