# Changing Constraint when Keyboard Appears - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a UIView that isn't moving properly when the keyboard appears. There is a UITextView in a UIView that I use to enter text. If I select the TextView to enter text, the keyboard appears but the UIView doesn't move THE FIRST TIME. If I tap the background and make the keyboard disappear and then tap on the TextView again, then the UIView moves up properly. Does anyone know what's happening here?

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIToolbarDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var composeTextView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var composeViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    composeTextView.delegate = self

}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue

    let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize?.height

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *){

            self.composeViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight! - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        }
        else {
            self.composeViewBottomConstraint.constant = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        }
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}

}
```

Comment: Hi badman, What do you want is move up your UIView when keyboard appear and move down when keyboard disappear right.

Comment: Yeah that's right Lenin.

Comment: check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643471/7083671

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that the view not going up in first click of the textView is that the showKeyboard observer is added in beginEditing , so this line should be in `viewDidLoad`

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

in addition to the following fixes

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

     // I think no need for it

}

 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {

     let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?  [UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue

     let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize?.height

     if #available(iOS 11.0, *){

          self.composeViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight! - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
      }
      else {
           self.composeViewBottomConstraint.constant = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
         }

       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5){

          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

       }


   }

  @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification){

      self.composeViewBottomConstraint.constant =  0 // or change according to your logic  

       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5){

          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

       }

  }
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Such a simple fix, I don't know how I missed it. Thanks.