# UITextfield hidden behind keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I am building an app that contains a search or a UITextField and it is located at the bottom of the view near the safe area, so when I touch it and the keyboard pops up, the textfield gets hidden behind the keyboard.

How can I make it so when the keyboard pops up the Textfield moves right above it?
Here is the code I have in the viewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var windLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchCItyTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchCItyTextField.delegate = self
    }
}
//MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate
extension UIViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
}
```

Here are the screenshots:
[image: ViewController without the keyboard]
[image: ViewController with keyboard]

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions/answers, here is one of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070242/move-view-with-keyboard-using-swift

Comment: You can use iqkeyboard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) for scroll the UITextField when open the KeyBoard

For Example

In AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true 
    return true
  }
```

In ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
  lazy var textField: UITextField! = {
    
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    textField.placeholder = "Enter"
    return textField
    
  }()
    
  override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
    return .darkContent
  }
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.setConstraint()
    
  }
    
  func setConstraint(){
    
    self.view.addSubview(self.textField)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    
      self.textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
      self.textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.66),
      self.textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
      self.textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
      
    ])

  }
  
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: While a 3rd-party class such as `IQKeyboardManager` *may* be useful, this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Hi @DonMag I suggest the IQKeyboardManager framework to him. its looks the framework is working fine for me. Please see the above my updated answer post.

Comment: Again, that *may* be useful, but it doesn't tell the OP anything about ***how*** to manage they keyboard. In addition, suppose development of `IQKeyboardManager` gets discontinued and is no longer available? Your suggestion would be completely appropriate for a **comment** - but it doesn't ***answer*** the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `@IBOutlet` for the bottom constraint of the text field and update this when the keyboard appears/disappears. For example, you set it to `-30` from the bottom when there's no keyboard and update it to `-keyboardHeight - 30` if the keyboard is present. See an example of [how this can be done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441226/changing-constraint-when-keyboard-appears-swift/49441295).

Another method would be to move the whole view up, for example by using a `UIScrollView`, increasing its height when the keyboard is present and scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe for you keyboard appears or disappears, and updated your interface

For example:

```
@objc func kbDidShow(notification: Notification) {


        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }

        let kbFrameSize = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

        yourTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalsTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: kbFrameSize.height + 50).isActive = true
        
    }

@objc func kbDidHide() {

       yourTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalsTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

    }
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(kbDidShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(kbDidHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
        
        
    }
```