# how to get the height of the keyboard including the suggestions bar in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I used :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
      if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
      let keyboardHeight : Int = Int(keyboardSize.height)
      print("keyboardHeight",keyboardHeight)
      KeyboardHeightVar = keyboardHeight
      }
}
```

to change to get the height of the keyboard, *but the height doesn't include the suggestions bar*. **How do I get the value of the keyboard height plus the suggestions bar height?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get height of Keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774006/how-to-get-height-of-keyboard)

Answer (score 9):

Using the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` returns the correct keyboard height.
For example, if the keyboard without the toolbar, it returns 216.0 height. With the toolbar - 260.0

Comment: it gets called twice for the first time and for rest of the time it is called once. Any reason?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have this problem. In the `viewDidLoad` you can do this:
`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)`

Comment: is thier anyway keyboardWillshow method gets called once?

Comment: Not sure if there's been a change in something, but on mine I get the exact same value for height using both methods, even though there is definitely a suggestion bar present.

Comment: For Swift4 4/5 I use this and it works:

let userInfo = notification.userInfo ?? [:]
        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
 let height = keyboardFrame.height

Comment: I also get the exact same values for both, with and without toolbar

Answer (score 5):

Use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardDidShow` instead of `UIKeyboardWillShow`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 

#selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                let keyboardHeight : Int = Int(keyboardSize.height)
                print("keyboardHeight",keyboardHeight)
                KeyboardHeightVar = keyboardHeight
            }

        }
```

Comment: that method only gets the height of the keyboard. I am trying to get the height including the suggestions bar

Answer (score 4):

Try using `UIKeyboardDidShow` instead.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
```

You'll get the callback in keyboardWasShown method whenever the keyboard is appear on the screen,

```
@objc func keyboardWasShown(_ notification : Notification)
{
    let info = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo
    let value = info?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
    if let rawFrame = (value as AnyObject).cgRectValue
    {
        let keyboardFrame = self.reportItTableView.convert(rawFrame, from: nil)
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.height //Height of the keyboard
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case, we lose the smooth animation!

Comment: This answer helped me, I am using the keyboard frame did change notification and retrieving the frame end user info value, but was not converting the keyboard frame to the enclosing view, once I did that then I get the correct result and can scroll the view correctly.

Comment: this method gets called 3 times giving me 3 different hights.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to register for notification that triggered when keyboard will be visible.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

Get keyboard height in method...

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {

 if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
 }
}
```