# How to the fix the problem in UIView animation?

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiviewanimation

Textfield animation view moves upward 240 then  the keyboard and view between there is a black background. I need to fix it.

The program I tried:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: 240)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(up: false, moveValue: 240)
}

func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
    let movementDuration:TimeInterval = 0.3
    let movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration )
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: 240)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(up: false, moveValue: 240)
}
```

I expect the black background colour to be replaced with the white background but it's not working. I tried with view background colour the actual colour I need white colour.

[image: my screen]

Comment: Make Outlet of view which you want to move up and set outlet instead of UIVIEW. and try

Comment: Instead of hard coded 240, get the height of the keyboard and move view to that value. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774006/how-to-get-height-of-keyboard) might help!.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the window color. You can try changing the color by 
`UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white`

Comment: @kranthibabu please upvote if the answer was correct

Comment: This is hack at its best :D. Will fail if the UIView background color is anything but white. Better option still would be to use keyboard height and move accordingly as mentioned by @Kamran in the comments section of the question

Comment: I was upvoted but its show "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."