# How do I adjust the size of a UITableView in viewDidLoad?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield, iqkeyboardmanager

I have a view controller with two elements: a `UITableView` and a `UIView` that contains a `UITextField`. I am also using the `IQKeyboardManager` library so that my `UITextField` is visible. Here is the code that controls them:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CommentCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CommentCell")
    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    commentTextField.delegate = self
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(handle(keyboardShowNotification:)),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification,
                                               object: nil)
    let textFieldHeight = commentCompositionView.frame.size.height
    let navBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?? 0.0
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: keyboardHeight, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height - (textFieldHeight + navBarHeight + keyboardHeight + 20))
    print("Did load: \(tableView.frame.size.height)")
}
    
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    commentTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    print("Did Appear: \(tableView.frame.size.height)")
}
    
    
    
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let textFieldHeight = commentCompositionView.frame.size.height
    let navBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?? 0.0
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: keyboardHeight, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height - (textFieldHeight + navBarHeight + keyboardHeight + 20))
    print("Did begin: \(tableView.frame.size.height)")
}
    
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let textFieldHeight = commentCompositionView.frame.size.height
    let navBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?? 0.0
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height - (textFieldHeight + navBarHeight + 20))
    print("Did end: \(tableView.frame.size.height)")
}
```

My problem is that when the view loads the `UITableView`'s height is too large and I cannot see the top of the table view. When I click out of and then back into the `UITableView` it works just fine but the first load does not work.

here is a sample of output where the view loads, I click out of the `UITextField` and then click back into it:

```
Did load: 465.0
Did begin: 465.0
Did Appear: 465.0
Did end: 465.0
Did begin: 211.0
Did end: 465.0
Did begin: 211.0
```

It seems to me that given that I am setting the height in `viewDidLoad` that the first three print statements should instead be `211.0`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I found what the issue is but am unsure of how to solve it. When the view first loads `keyboardHeight` is 0.0. It is not until I have closed and reopened the keyboard that it gives me an accurate number.

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774006/how-to-get-height-of-keyboard) answer to get `keyboardHeight`

Comment: Have you tried implementing your layout code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? This is all likely caused by the view not correctly being layed out at the time you request the size

Comment: @Bram I just tried moving the line where I set `tableView.frame` from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and I get the same result.

Comment: I also tried it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, same problem

Comment: @David how is your table view created? if it's in storyboard than you can't change frame of it, you need to setup your constraints

Comment: @Philip my table view is created programmatically. I am able to change the size of it. The problem is that the size is not changing at the correct times.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I needed to set the `UITableView` height in `viewDidAppear` once I did that my problem was solved:

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    commentTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    let textFieldHeight = commentCompositionView.frame.size.height
    let navBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?? 0.0
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: keyboardHeight, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height - (textFieldHeight + navBarHeight + keyboardHeight + 20))
}
```