# iOS Custom Keyboard Short Height

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I am working on an iOS custom keyboard extension. My keyboard appears shorter than regular keyboard. See this:

[image: Keyboard height is short]

Please follow these steps to produce the result:

1. Create an xCode project and add a Keyboard Extension target
2. Add a new Storyboard file and change plist to use the newly added Storyboard. (You can follow a tutorial on Youtube "How To Create a Custom Keyboard Using Storyboard Xcode" )
3. Add a `UIViewController` and drag 2 `UIButtons` to the view controller.
4. Set constraints as in this:
   [image: set top, left, bottom, same width and height constraints]
5. The `UIButtons` should be stretched and have equal height.
6. Run it. The keyboard height is shorter than normal and the 2 buttons don't look as they do in the storyboard.

Development Environment:

- Macbook Pro, MacOS X El Capitan, 8GB RAM, 512GB SSD
- xCode 8.0 (8A218a)
- Tested on all iPhone simulators

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue (xcode 8.3), my keyboard would be smaller then the standard one ([default settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuJD1.jpg)). For organising the keys I use stack views which help layout the buttons without hard constraints. 
What I do to preserve the height of the keyboard is setting the relation of height constraints for each stack view to "Greater Than or Equal" (Default value is Equal):
[new settings and preserved keyboard height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBqs6.jpg)

best,
Yury

Answer (score 0):

Did you use constraint for height for your keyboard's view? If no, try to set this.

Also, put a checkmark to 'height' value in your screenshot for a buttons (or just make a ctrl-drag from the button to herself and choose 'height' item in the pop-up - this will work for keyboard's view too).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have solved this by adding height constraint to the view. But then the height is fixed in both orientations and also on all devices. Is there way to get default height of iOS keyboard?

Comment: @ChandarongNuon Glad it helped. To get default iOS keyboard height You could use `CGFloat height = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].height;

   self.YourConstraint.constant = height;
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];` that code. It will return you 224 in portrait (you can also just use this value in constraint in storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by setting a new constrain for the height 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have solved this by adding height constraint to the view. But then the height is fixed in both orientations and also on all devices. Is there way to get default height of iOS keyboard?

Comment: @ChandarongNuon Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284321/what-is-the-height-of-iphones-onscreen-keyboard