# How to get keyboard height in viewDidLoad not after keyboard opens

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set a view frame to be above the keyboard.
That it will not need to change height/location after keyboard appears.

Is there a way to get keyboard height in ViewDidLoad and not after keyboard appears?

Thanks

---

with and without keyboard the view should always be in the same place.

[image]

Comment: Check this :  http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Comment: what u r trying to do with this ?

Comment: i added an image for explanation

Comment: if user is using a custom keyboard, you wont exactly know the height until the keyboard is about to be shown, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27798712/1219956)

Comment: Event if the user is using a custom keyboard, IOS knows about it.

Comment: if u really want the UI should be that way . then u should hard code those heights based on devices .

Comment: check out this  http://arsenkin.com/how-to-get-ios-keyboard-height-programmatically.html

Comment: The keyboard height depends on the model, the QuickType bar, user settings but fairly anyone can say that keyboard height is 216pts for portrait and 162pts for Landscape. Again it must be a good idea if you calculate it dynamically.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS this is with notifications, a not what i need, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are fixed sizes for Keyboard heights in iOS.

Here's some documentation that would help you. 
http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

You can just check what device is being using and find its keyboard height accordingly.

Comment: How do i check if there is a custom keyboard? or if the QuickType is on screen?