# Mobile web - How to get the screen's height when the keyboard is open

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, mobile-safari

I need to know the actual visible height of my web app for different calculations.

I'm having a problem getting this height on iOS Safari when the soft keyboard is open, the height stays the same (by using `window.innerHeight`).

Is there any way to get the "new" screen size when the virtual keyboard is open?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS7 Detect keyboard height with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148014/ios7-detect-keyboard-height-with-javascript)

Comment: @Hydrothermal Seems like the question answers on how to trigger the keyboard popping up which I have no problem with.
There's a comment on the answer asking how to solve my problem.

Answer (score -2):

window height when the keyboard is shown = (window.innerHeight - keyboard.height)
you can get the keyboard height in different ways depending on the plugin you are using

Comment: This is a web app, how can I infer the keyboard size?
As far as I know, I can't.