# What is the height of the iOS keyboard in pixels for the iPadAir?

Tags: ios, keyboard

This is for graphic design reasons, so height in pixels is preferred. 
I think different language keyboards may have different heights if that is the case. Then height of USA/UK keyboard would be preferable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the height of iPad's onscreen keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213878/what-is-the-height-of-ipads-onscreen-keyboard)

Comment: The keyboard can have many different shapes on the iPad. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14178620/1329214

Answer (score 1):

You should get it programatically, it is the best way, register for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector (keyboardDidShow:) name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

And then get the frame:

```
-(void) keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];
    NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [aValue CGRectValue];
}
```

Whish it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can get height of keyboard, whenever it gets showed:

```
//add this line to viewDidLoad    
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyBordShown name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

- (void)keyBordShown:NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
}
```

As this will be better approach than statically setting height of keyboard.