# Notification for change of iPad keyboard height

Tags: ipad, keyboard, notifications

I am trying to show a UITextField on top of the iPad keyboard.

I was able to get the height of the keyboard when it was presented with the notification.

However, in iPad, by change the language input of the keyboard -> most likely to Japanese, the height of the keyboard changed because a text-hypothesis area was shown on top of the keyboard, that caused my UITextfield hidden by that area....

Does anybody know how can I get the height changed notification or any other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adjusting interface when keyboard appears for UITextField or UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402658/adjusting-interface-when-keyboard-appears-for-uitextfield-or-uitextview)

Comment: I did resize my view but the problem is that, in iPad, according to the language of the keyboard, the height changed. And seems like there is no notification when the height of keyboard is changed as the keyboard is already visible.

Comment: Really? I thought all keyboards were the same height.

Comment: In iPad, Japanese and Chinese keyboard show a suggested list on top of the keyboard.. which make it taller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that when you switch languages, the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` fires for each change, so you always get the updated height.

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743140/ipad-keyboard-dimensions/7302291#7302291) on how to set up responses to the showing and hiding, and getting the height.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift**

The `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` won't fire anymore the keyboard size change.

Use `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` instead:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(instance.keyboardWillChange(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

at the function:

```
let targetSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()
```

**Important:** this event will be fired also when keyboard will open and will hide, can replace both `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` if only sizes are needed